# Como resolver error al ejecutar migración con laravel?

Tags: php, postgresql

tengo un proyecto con laravel y cuando intento ejecutar las migraciones realizadas. me devuelve el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una conexión con postgresql. Los paquetes necesarios para php estan correctamente configurados en mi php.ini.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La conexión correctamente configurada en mi archivo .env.
He intentado forzar laas migraciones sin conseguir efecto diferente
Agradezco su colaboración

Comment: ya cambiaste en `app/config/database.php` esta línea: `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),` para que tenga ahora `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'postgres'),`

Comment: Si... Ya hice ese cambio

Comment: ¿cómo está la configuración en el .env?

Comment: cuidado. Deberias tener `dos` php.ini. Uno de tu apache, y otro de la consola. Ten en cuenta que los comandos utilizan una configuracion diferente de php. En windows no se donde estan esos archivos, en linux es el archivo `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`. Por ello mismo, hay que configurar las extensiones en la consola.

Comment: Mi archivo .env esta configurado de la sig manera.

`DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=dbusername
DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword`